# I am trying to make a program that asks a user for file.txt and use the frequency of the letters to draw a bar chart. And i am stack

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that asks a user for file.txt and uses the frequency of the letters to draw a bar chart. And I am stuck. I'm not able to get the frequency of the letters to draw the bar graph. I need help accessing the count of the letters to calculate the height of the chart.

```
package com.company;

import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BarGraph {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

     // getting file name from user
     Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.print("Please enter a file name: ");

     String myFile=input.nextLine().trim();

     // using HashMap to store characters
     HashMap<Integer,Integer> hash = new HashMap<>();

     // reading each line of text
     BufferedReader nyk = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));
     String m;

      while (true) {
          String eachline = nyk.readLine();
          if (eachline==null){break;}// breaks if there is nothing on the line
          m = eachline.toLowerCase();// setting all characters to lower case
          for (int i=0; i<m.length();i++){
               char x = m.charAt(i);
              if (x!= ' '){
                 int charvalue = hash.getOrDefault((int) x,0);// setting default value to 0
                 hash.put((int) x , charvalue +1 );// increasing the value of the character
              }
          }

      }

    nyk.close();

      for (int character: hash.keySet()){
          System.out.println((char) character + "= "+ hash.get(character));

      }


     }}

class Bars extends JPanel{

 public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
     super.paintComponent(g);


 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Bars t = new Bars();
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
     jf.setTitle("Barchart");
     jf.setSize(600,400);
     jf.setVisible(true);
     jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     jf.add(t);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this set up as two different classes, each with their own "main" method.  Presumably you only want to be running one of them.  The thing to do, from what I can see, would be to define "Bars" as an inner class (or at least a separate class that "BarGraph" has a dependency on) and move all of the code you have in its "main" method to a constructor instead (or maybe some sort of "init" method if you prefer.)

Once that's done, you add code in the "main" method of BarGraph, after you're done parsing your file, to actually create one of these "Bars" objects and initialize it.  Once it's initialized, you can create a method in "Bars" to add data to the graph from your "hash" data structure and use that method from within BarGraph's main method.

Comment: Can you tell me how to make bars an inner class

Comment: You just put the declaration for the Bars class inside the BarGraph class, like you were declaring a method.